# Printing the line above the current executing line

Tags: python

**Is there a way for a line of code in a Python script to print the line above it?**

---

**UPDATE:**
Motivations

- It's an intriguing problem. I was wondering if Python's strong introspection goes that far.
- I was saving this for a follow up question - I actually don't want to "print the line above", but rather to grab a certain line of code (I'll know which only in run-time), disassemble it and understand which variables are mentioned. I'll explain why in the follow-up :)

Comment: Perhaps, but why would you need that? Don't you know what code you're writing?

Comment: I'm not aware of a nice way to achieve this, but nothing is impossible. Why would you need that? Explain a bit more, there must be a nicer way to achieve whatever you want.

Comment: i agree w/ demian, inspect is pretty cool...not sure what you can leverage out of it, but http://wiki.python.org/moin/ByteplayDoc is pretty darn amazing

Answer (score 2):

**To read (with your eyes)** you can use PDB

Just import pdb and then you can do this:

code:

```
a = 'test'
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

After running a code you will get stopped in shell like enviroment and you will be able to do this:

```
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) print a
test
(Pdb) l
  1     a = 'test';
  2  -> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
[EOF]
```

So you want to look at l(ist) command:

> List source code for the current file. Without arguments, list 11
>   lines around the current line or continue the previous listing. With
>   one argument, list 11 lines around at that line. With two arguments,
>   list the given range; if the second argument is less than the first,
>   it is interpreted as a count.

More in http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

---

**If you wish to automate code morphing** -

> Other languages, such as Perl, Python and JavaScript, allow programs
>   to create new code at run-time and execute it using an eval function,
>   but do not allow existing code to be mutated. The illusion of
>   modification (even though no machine code is really being overwritten)
>   is achieved by modifying function pointers

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

---

**If you wish to automate code reading**, but not morphing, you can use linecache as shown in here http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html and just instead of printing put it into a list and get whatever value you want :)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking the wrong question (maybe?) - are you looking to get the last item in the call stack? If so, you could possibly do something like this:

```
import inspect

def do_add(a, b):
        if type(a) is not int or type(b) is not int:
                print inspect.stack()[1] # last stack item
                return None

        return a + b

do_add(1, 3)
do_add(1, 'asd')
```

http://ideone.com/IpdQa

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the complexity, and this is probably ill advised, you can read in your python file w/ readlines(), print them, and then call exec() on them in a looping structure.

example for those dumb enough to suggest that this isn't possible in the limited scope i was referring to.

```
>>> a = ["a=1+1","b=a","print b"]
>>> for item in a:
...     print item
...     exec(item)
... 
a=1+1
b=a
print b
2
>>>
```

Comment: -1: Not only is the weird, it won't work: you can't exec() a whole file a line at a time.

Comment: seriously, a down-vote.  I didn't say it was a good idea and i said it depended on complexity.  if your file is a set of math operations there's no reason this wouldn't work